# How to assign an parameter as a object to a web service API by soapUI?

Tags: soapui

I am using soapUI to test my web service API, but some field/ parameter which is an object rather then standard data type, e.g.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xml>
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <api:test>
         <api:giveMeSomeText>BEEF1234567890</api:giveMeSomeText>
         <api:giveMeJavaURLObject>??????</api:giveMeJavaURLObject>
      </api:test>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How to assign an parameter as a object to a web service API by soapUI? Could I use a CDATA string to bundle my object, how to do it?

```
<![CDATA[??????]]>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use CDATA, please see the below sample

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:sam="http://www.example.org/sample/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <sam:searchResponse>
         <sam:searchResponse>
            <item><id>1234</id><description><![CDATA[<item><width>123</width><height>345</height>
<length>098</length><isle>A34</isle></item>]]></description><price>123</price>
            </item>
         </sam:searchResponse>
      </sam:searchResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```